# Wordpress losing session with chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, cookies, payment

since a few weeks we are noticing, that customers returning from checkout sporadically lose their login status. We have found out that this happens only with chrome versions around 88. What I was able to find out was, that the usual check

```
isset(WC()->session->chosen_payment_method)
```

returns false when using chrome and returns true when using firefox or other browsers (even edge and safari do work as intended)

Does anyone know how to "fight" this?

So far I have tried to find out, how to pass the sessionid via an url parameter to rebuild the cookie after the user is redirected back from the 3rd party sites. But wasn't really lucky and it even seems like a security risk to do soo as this would enable man in the middle attacks.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the `SameSite` attribute of the cookie. https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html (Although then you should rather been having seeing problem since Feb 2020 already, Chrome started enforcing this with v80.)

Comment: I doubt it, `SameSite` cookies are supported by every browser (except IE obviously). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#browser_compatibility. How did you noticed the problem in first place? Is there any metrics behind it? Was the issue observed on multiple OS too (Beside browsers)?

Comment: I had these issues with chrome 80, then the rolled it back and it was working on the next release. Then I left the project for a time being and now I can see that it is behaving exactly the same way as before. I can reproduce this error on mac and windows. Don't have any linux lying arount atm.

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed related to `SameSite` cookies, then like @CBroe suggested, the issue should have showed up since at least January.

The Chromium people have published an article in regards to potential issues, how to detect them and fix them. You can have a look at it here [Tips for testing and debugging SameSite-by-default and “SameSite=None; Secure” cookies](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug).

Here are some ressources to get started on a fix if it is indeed linked to `SameSite` cookies.

- SameSite cookie recipes @ https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/
- SameSite examples @ https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples

But once again, as it only affect Chromium users then I doubt it's related to `SameSite` cookies.